# "Some of the properties for this Web Part cannot be set or displayed properly"

Tags: web-part

Im getting this error when trying to add a custome property to a webpart, what have I done wrong?

```
    [WebBrowsable(true),
    Personalizable(true),
    WebDisplayName("Site Root"),
    WebDescription("blah blah"),
    Category("Custome Settings"),
    WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)]
    public string SiteRoot
    {
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["SiteRoot"] = value; }
    }
```

(Image of error is here, cant put it the question as new users cant use the image tag!?! wtf?)

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d1bdd5989c.png

Answer (score 1):

A web part property is used to bind configuration settings to and from the web part settings database.

Your command:

```
set { HttpContext.Current.Session["SiteRoot"] = value; }
```

does not make sense to put in a property

It should be something like this

```
private string _siteroot;
[WebBrowsable(true),
    Personalizable(true),
    WebDisplayName("Site Root"),
    WebDescription("blah blah"),
    Category("Custome Settings"),
    WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)]
public string SiteRoot {
    get { return _siteroot; }
    set { _siteroot = value; }
}
```

And then you can use the property like this

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);

    if(!IsPostBack) {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["SiteRoot"] = SiteRoot;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats fixed it, but how do I access the property in the code behind of the usercontrol for my Visual webpart.

Comment: its public, it should be accessible by <%= SiteRoot %>

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/create-a-custom-web-part-for-sharepoint-2010/) post. It shows creating a custom property, and accessing that property from the code behind of your user control.